# How to get the magento developer ip?

Tags: magento, ip

I use this code to have a js popup on each side telling visitors that the shop is not productive:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($ip == 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' OR $ip == 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx') { ?>
You are a developer
<?php } else { ?> 
You are a visitor
<?php } ?>
```

My question is, how can I use the developer Ip from the magento backend in this code
->System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Developer Client Restrictions

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Developer Client Restrictions will restrict access to IPs specified. I don't think this is what you need.

Comment: I guess he wants to use `dev/restrict/allow_ips` somewhere in the frontend to have different output for developers than normal users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can get this like any other config value

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips', $storeId)
Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips')
```

and then

or just

```
<?php $isDeveloper = (strstr(Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips', $storeId), Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr())) ? true : false; ?>
```

or just (as pointed by MagePsycho in comments)

```
if(Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed()){ }
```

Comment: Even simpler form will be: if(Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed()){ }

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$allowedIps = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips', $storeId);
        $remoteAddr = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
        if (!empty($allowedIps) && !empty($remoteAddr)) {
            $allowedIps = preg_split('#\s*,\s*#', $allowedIps, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            if (array_search($remoteAddr, $allowedIps) === false
                && array_search(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpHost(), !$allowedIps) === false) {
               ?>
You are a visitor
<?php } else { ?>
You are a developer
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips');
```